# If statement using a pandas column as a condition and the users´ input

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataset

I'm having lots of problems to solve this:
I want to use the users input to search in a data set and give the users the complete row that's the same of its input.
The code I've done is something like that, but I don't know how to fix the problems in the if statement, any suggestion'll be great.

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delimiter = '\t')

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

a.set_index('Rank', inplace = True)
user_rank = input('Choose the rank: ')

if int(user_rank) == all(a.iloc['Rank']):
  print(a.loc[user_rank])
else:
  print('Error')
```

Comment: Try: `print(a[a['Rank'] == user_rank])`

Comment: Hello! You should check out the difference between iloc and loc. iloc is "integer location", and is therefore better suited for use with integer indexes. In your conditional statement, you apply `iloc` to a string. This may be causing some of your issues.

Comment: _I don´t know how to fix the problems in the if statement_ What problems? Have you read the Pandas documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution would be:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delimiter = '\t')

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

a.set_index('Rank', inplace = True)
user_rank = input('Choose the rank: ')

if int(user_rank) == all(a.loc['Rank']):
  print(a.loc[user_rank])
else:
  print('Error')
```